# .NET Equivalent of Snipping Tool

Tags: .net, screen, screenshot, capture

I'm looking for .NET code which performs the same as Snipping Tool - capturing a screen area.
I believe it uses hooks. Would be interesting to know how does it highlight the selected fragment.

Update:
Found http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Screen_Shot.aspx . Though people say it's missing some important files for proper compilation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The snipping tool effect isn't difficult to implement in Windows Forms.  Add a new form to your project and name it "SnippingTool".  Make the code look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class SnippingTool : Form {
        public static Image Snip() {
            var rc = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)) {
                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                using (var snipper = new SnippingTool(bmp)) {
                    if (snipper.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                        return snipper.Image;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public SnippingTool(Image screenShot) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackgroundImage = screenShot;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
        public Image Image { get; set; }

        private Rectangle rcSelect = new Rectangle();
        private Point pntStart;

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
            // Start the snip on mouse down
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
            pntStart = e.Location;
            rcSelect = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(0, 0));
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
            // Modify the selection on mouse move
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
            int x1 = Math.Min(e.X, pntStart.X);
            int y1 = Math.Min(e.Y, pntStart.Y);
            int x2 = Math.Max(e.X, pntStart.X);
            int y2 = Math.Max(e.Y, pntStart.Y);
            rcSelect = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
            // Complete the snip on mouse-up
            if (rcSelect.Width <= 0 || rcSelect.Height <= 0) return;
            Image = new Bitmap(rcSelect.Width, rcSelect.Height);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(Image)) {
                gr.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height),
                    rcSelect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
            // Draw the current selection
            using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, Color.White))) {
                int x1 = rcSelect.X; int x2 = rcSelect.X + rcSelect.Width;
                int y1 = rcSelect.Y; int y2 = rcSelect.Y + rcSelect.Height;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(0, 0, x1, this.Height));
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x2, 0, this.Width - x2, this.Height));
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x1, 0, x2 - x1, y1));
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, this.Height - y2));
            }
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3)) {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rcSelect);
            }
        }
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
            // Allow canceling the snip with the Escape key
            if (keyData == Keys.Escape) this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var bmp = SnippingTool.Snip();
if (bmp != null) {
    // Do something with the bitmap
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hans, could you help to make this tool compatible with secondary monitors? Tried adding a screen parameter, and adjusting snipper position according it, but getting unexpected results.

Comment: What do you expect me to do with "unexpected results"?  Start a new question and *really* document your problem.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005910/make-net-snipping-tool-compatible-with-multiple-monitors

Answer (score 11):

This is a modified @Hans's version that is compatible with multiple monitors and works well with DPI scaling (tested on Windows 7 and Windows 10).

```
public sealed partial class SnippingTool : Form
{
    public static event EventHandler Cancel;
    public static event EventHandler AreaSelected;
    public static Image Image { get; set; }

    private static SnippingTool[] _forms;
    private Rectangle _rectSelection;
    private Point _pointStart;

    public SnippingTool(Image screenShot, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundImage = screenShot;
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        SetBounds(x, y, width, height);
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        TopMost = true;
    }

    private void OnCancel(EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancel?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnAreaSelected(EventArgs e)
    {
        AreaSelected?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void CloseForms()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _forms.Length; i++)
        {
            _forms[i].Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void Snip()
    {
        var screens = ScreenHelper.GetMonitorsInfo();
        _forms = new SnippingTool[screens.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < screens.Count; i++)
        {
            int hRes = screens[i].HorizontalResolution;
            int vRes = screens[i].VerticalResolution;
            int top = screens[i].MonitorArea.Top;
            int left = screens[i].MonitorArea.Left;
            var bmp = new Bitmap(hRes, vRes, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
            }
            _forms[i] = new SnippingTool(bmp, left, top, hRes, vRes);
            _forms[i].Show();
        }
    }

    #region Overrides
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Start the snip on mouse down
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            return;
        }
        _pointStart = e.Location;
        _rectSelection = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(0, 0));
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Modify the selection on mouse move
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            return;
        }
        int x1 = Math.Min(e.X, _pointStart.X);
        int y1 = Math.Min(e.Y, _pointStart.Y);
        int x2 = Math.Max(e.X, _pointStart.X);
        int y2 = Math.Max(e.Y, _pointStart.Y);
        _rectSelection = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Complete the snip on mouse-up
        if (_rectSelection.Width <= 0 || _rectSelection.Height <= 0)
        {
            CloseForms();
            OnCancel(new EventArgs());
            return;
        }
        Image = new Bitmap(_rectSelection.Width, _rectSelection.Height);
        var hScale = BackgroundImage.Width / (double)Width;
        var vScale = BackgroundImage.Height / (double)Height;
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(Image))
        {

            gr.DrawImage(BackgroundImage, 
                new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height),
                new Rectangle((int)(_rectSelection.X * hScale), (int)(_rectSelection.Y * vScale), (int)(_rectSelection.Width * hScale), (int)(_rectSelection.Height * vScale)),  
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        CloseForms();
        OnAreaSelected(new EventArgs());
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw the current selection
        using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, Color.White)))
        {
            int x1 = _rectSelection.X;
            int x2 = _rectSelection.X + _rectSelection.Width;
            int y1 = _rectSelection.Y;
            int y2 = _rectSelection.Y + _rectSelection.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(0, 0, x1, Height));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x2, 0, Width - x2, Height));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x1, 0, x2 - x1, y1));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, Height - y2));
        }
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _rectSelection);
        }
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        // Allow canceling the snip with the Escape key
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            Image = null;
            CloseForms();
            OnCancel(new EventArgs());
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Usage:

```
SnippingTool.AreaSelected += OnAreaSelected; 
SnippingTool.Snip();

private static void OnAreaSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = SnippingTool.Image;
    // Do something with the bitmap
    //...
}
```

Note you need a helper class to get the actual monitor resolution and avoid problems with DPI scaling. 
This is the code:

```
public class DeviceInfo
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public int VerticalResolution { get; set; }
    public int HorizontalResolution { get; set; }
    public Rectangle MonitorArea { get; set; }
}
public static class ScreenHelper
{
    private const int DektopVertRes = 117;
    private const int DesktopHorzRes = 118;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Rect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal struct MONITORINFOEX
    {
        public int Size;
        public Rect Monitor;
        public Rect WorkArea;
        public uint Flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
    }
    private delegate bool MonitorEnumDelegate(IntPtr hMonitor, IntPtr hdcMonitor, ref Rect lprcMonitor, IntPtr dwData);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lprcClip, MonitorEnumDelegate lpfnEnum, IntPtr dwData);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateDC(string lpszDriver, string lpszDevice, string lpszOutput, IntPtr lpInitData);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, ref MONITORINFOEX lpmi);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

    private static List<DeviceInfo> _result;

    public static List<DeviceInfo> GetMonitorsInfo()
    {
        _result = new List<DeviceInfo>();
        EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, MonitorEnum, IntPtr.Zero);
        return _result;
    }

    private static bool MonitorEnum(IntPtr hMonitor, IntPtr hdcMonitor, ref Rect lprcMonitor, IntPtr dwData)
    {
        var mi = new MONITORINFOEX();
        mi.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFOEX));
        bool success = GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, ref mi);
        if (success)
        {
            var dc = CreateDC(mi.DeviceName, mi.DeviceName, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            var di = new DeviceInfo
            {
                DeviceName = mi.DeviceName,
                MonitorArea = new Rectangle(mi.Monitor.left, mi.Monitor.top, mi.Monitor.right-mi.Monitor.right, mi.Monitor.bottom-mi.Monitor.top),
                VerticalResolution = GetDeviceCaps(dc, DektopVertRes),
                HorizontalResolution = GetDeviceCaps(dc, DesktopHorzRes)
            };
            ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, dc);
            _result.Add(di);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the complete [source code](https://github.com/thepirat000/Snipping-Ocr/tree/master/Snipping%20OCR/SnippingTool)

Comment: It works, But in high Dpi while snipping the image is blurry and if you save it the image is too small, tried to fix it but couldn't. @thepirat000

Comment: @Arvand What's your DPI configuration?

Comment: 3840x2160 with text size set to 250% [4K display]

Comment: @thepirat000 thx, works great !! I would like to know how I could modify the prog. to be able make a snip through two monitors ?? Actually your Tool is not able to leave the selected monitor.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a full-screen screenshot, then (probably) copies it, applies the translucent effect & displays it. When you click-drag it can then overlay the corresponding region from the original capture.

You can get a screenshot using [`CopyFromScreen()`](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html) or using the [GDI API](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. That makes sense. 
Perhaps you know how can that "whitening" effect can be applied to bitmap?