# Make .NET snipping tool compatible with multiple monitors

Tags: .net, screen, screenshot, capture

An alternative snipping tool solution was provided in this posting: [.NET Equivalent of Snipping Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123776/net-equivalent-of-snipping-tool)

Now it's necessary to make it work for selected screens (on multi-monitor systems).

The code has been modified accordingly:

```
Public Class SnippingTool


    Private Shared _Screen As Screen

    Private Shared BitmapSize As Size

    Private Shared Graph As Graphics


    Public Shared Function Snip(ByVal screen As Screen) As Image

        _Screen = screen

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)

        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

        Graph = gr


        gr.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None '###

        BitmapSize = bmp.Size


        Using snipper = New SnippingTool(bmp)

            snipper.Location = New Point(screen.Bounds.Left, screen.Bounds.Top)

            If snipper.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Return snipper.Image
            End If

        End Using

        Return Nothing


    End Function



    Public Sub New(ByVal screenShot As Image)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.BackgroundImage = screenShot
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None


        'Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
    Public Property Image() As Image
        Get
            Return m_Image
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Image)
            m_Image = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Image As Image


    Private rcSelect As New Rectangle()
    Private pntStart As Point

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        ' Start the snip on mouse down
        If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left Then
            Return
        End If
        pntStart = e.Location
        rcSelect = New Rectangle(e.Location, New Size(0, 0))
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        ' Modify the selection on mouse move
        If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim x1 As Integer = Math.Min(e.X, pntStart.X)
        Dim y1 As Integer = Math.Min(e.Y, pntStart.Y)
        Dim x2 As Integer = Math.Max(e.X, pntStart.X)
        Dim y2 As Integer = Math.Max(e.Y, pntStart.Y)
        rcSelect = New Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub


    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        ' Complete the snip on mouse-up
        If rcSelect.Width <= 0 OrElse rcSelect.Height <= 0 Then
            Return
        End If
        Image = New Bitmap(rcSelect.Width, rcSelect.Height)
        Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image)
            gr.DrawImage(Me.BackgroundImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height), rcSelect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        ' Draw the current selection
        Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, Color.White))
            Dim x1 As Integer = rcSelect.X
            Dim x2 As Integer = rcSelect.X + rcSelect.Width
            Dim y1 As Integer = rcSelect.Y
            Dim y2 As Integer = rcSelect.Y + rcSelect.Height
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 0, x1, Me.Height))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(x2, 0, Me.Width - x2, Me.Height))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(x1, 0, x2 - x1, y1))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, Me.Height - y2))
        End Using
        Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rcSelect)
        End Using
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        ' Allow canceling the snip with the Escape key
        If keyData = Keys.Escape Then
            Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        Me.Size = New Size(_Screen.Bounds.Width, _Screen.Bounds.Height)
        Dim area = _Screen.WorkingArea
        Graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, area.Y, area.Y, BitmapSize)
    End Sub

End Class
```

But it refuses to work as expected. The snipper doesn't appear on the selected screen, instead it appears on the first one, regardless of the "screen" parameter in "Snip" function. 
How to make it work correctly?

**UPDATE**: The latest snipper version appears on correct screen, but blank.

**UPDATE X2** : The code above has been updated to reflect the latest version, which now works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `Screen.WorkingArea` property rather than `Screen.Bounds`.
The second option yields incorrect results with `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`.
Code snippet above has been updated with fully functional version.

Answer (score 3):

LoveDotNet, I believe there is a small problem with your source code, the following line:

`Graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, area.Y, area.Y, BitmapSize)`

Should be:

`Graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, 0, 0, BitmapSize)`

Also, just a quick tip to anyone who wants to use this code you can invoke it like the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim img As Image = SnippingTool.Snip(Screen.AllScreens(0)) 'Set to (1) for secondary monitor'
End Sub
```

Also, when you create your SnippingTool form, be sure to change the `StartPosition` property to `Manual`.

**Big Edit:**

I did some work to support multiple monitors at once, which doesn't require the developer to select which monitor to use (this clones the "Snipping Tool" a little closer).

Basically I'm iterating through all of the screens to find the minimum `X` and `Y` coordinates, and the largest `Right` and `Bottom`, this lets us evaluate the full size of the "Virtual Monitor":

I've tested it with my configuration which is:

`Primary 1280x800`

`Secondary 1280x1024 w/ -224 X offset`

[image]

Code:

> ```
> 'SnippingTool Code: Place this in a new form (set the StartUp Property to Manual)'
> Public Class SnippingTool
>
>
> Private Shared _Screen As Screen
>
> Private Shared BitmapSize As Size
>
> Private Shared Graph As Graphics
>
> Private Structure MultiScreenSize
>     Dim minX As Integer
>     Dim minY As Integer
>     Dim maxRight As Integer
>     Dim maxBottom As Integer
> End Structure
>
>
> Private Shared Function FindMultiScreenSize() As MultiScreenSize
>
>     Dim minX As Integer = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.X
>     Dim minY As Integer = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Y
>
>     Dim maxRight As Integer = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Right
>     Dim maxBottom As Integer = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Bottom
>
>     For Each aScreen As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
>         If aScreen.Bounds.X < minX Then
>             minX = aScreen.Bounds.X
>         End If
>
>         If aScreen.Bounds.Y < minY Then
>             minY = aScreen.Bounds.Y
>         End If
>
>         If aScreen.Bounds.Right > maxRight Then
>             maxRight = aScreen.Bounds.Right
>         End If
>
>         If aScreen.Bounds.Bottom > maxBottom Then
>             maxBottom = aScreen.Bounds.Bottom
>         End If
>     Next
>     Dim m_MultiScreenSize As MultiScreenSize
>     With m_MultiScreenSize
>         .minX = minX
>         .minY = minY
>         .maxBottom = maxBottom
>         .maxRight = maxRight
>     End With
>     Return m_MultiScreenSize
> End Function
> Public Shared Function Snip() As Image
>     Dim m_MultiScreenSize As MultiScreenSize = FindMultiScreenSize()
>
>     Dim bmp As New Bitmap(m_MultiScreenSize.maxRight - m_MultiScreenSize.minX, _
>                           m_MultiScreenSize.maxBottom - m_MultiScreenSize.minY, _
>                           System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
>     Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
>
>     Graph = gr
>
>
>     gr.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None 
>     BitmapSize = bmp.Size
>
>
>     Using snipper = New SnippingTool(bmp)
>
>         snipper.Location = New Point(m_MultiScreenSize.minX, m_MultiScreenSize.minY)
>
>         If snipper.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
>             Return snipper.Image
>         End If
>
>     End Using
>
>     Return Nothing
>
>
> End Function
>
>
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal screenShot As Image)
>     InitializeComponent()
>     Me.BackgroundImage = screenShot
>     Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
>     Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
>
>     Me.DoubleBuffered = True
> End Sub
> Public Property Image() As Image
>     Get
>         Return m_Image
>     End Get
>     Set(ByVal value As Image)
>         m_Image = Value
>     End Set
> End Property
> Private m_Image As Image
>
>
> Private rcSelect As New Rectangle()
> Private pntStart As Point
>
> Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
>     ' Start the snip on mouse down'
>     If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left Then
>         Return
>     End If
>     pntStart = e.Location
>     rcSelect = New Rectangle(e.Location, New Size(0, 0))
>     Me.Invalidate()
> End Sub
> Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
>     ' Modify the selection on mouse move'
>     If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left Then
>         Return
>     End If
>     Dim x1 As Integer = Math.Min(e.X, pntStart.X)
>     Dim y1 As Integer = Math.Min(e.Y, pntStart.Y)
>     Dim x2 As Integer = Math.Max(e.X, pntStart.X)
>     Dim y2 As Integer = Math.Max(e.Y, pntStart.Y)
>     rcSelect = New Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
>     Me.Invalidate()
> End Sub
>
>
> Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
>     ' Complete the snip on mouse-up'
>     If rcSelect.Width <= 0 OrElse rcSelect.Height <= 0 Then
>         Return
>     End If
>     Image = New Bitmap(rcSelect.Width, rcSelect.Height)
>     Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image)
>         gr.DrawImage(Me.BackgroundImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height), _
>                      rcSelect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
>     End Using
>     DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
> End Sub
> Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
>     ' Draw the current selection'
>     Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, Color.White))
>         Dim x1 As Integer = rcSelect.X
>         Dim x2 As Integer = rcSelect.X + rcSelect.Width
>         Dim y1 As Integer = rcSelect.Y
>         Dim y2 As Integer = rcSelect.Y + rcSelect.Height
>         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(0, 0, x1, Me.Height))
>         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(x2, 0, Me.Width - x2, Me.Height))
>         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(x1, 0, x2 - x1, y1))
>         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, New Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, Me.Height - y2))
>     End Using
>     Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
>         e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rcSelect)
>     End Using
> End Sub
> Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
>     ' Allow canceling the snip with the Escape key'
>     If keyData = Keys.Escape Then
>         Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
>     End If
>     Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
> End Function
>
> Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
>     MyBase.OnLoad(e)
>     Dim m_MultiScreenSize As MultiScreenSize = FindMultiScreenSize()
>     Me.Size = New Size(m_MultiScreenSize.maxRight - m_MultiScreenSize.minX, _
>                        m_MultiScreenSize.maxBottom - m_MultiScreenSize.minY)
>
>     Graph.CopyFromScreen(m_MultiScreenSize.minX, m_MultiScreenSize.minY, 0, 0, BitmapSize)
> End Sub
>  End Class
> ```

And you can call it like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim img As Image = SnippingTool.Snip()
    img.Save("C:\ScreenShot.png")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but by the time `Bitmap bmp =  bmp = new Bitmap(m_MultiScreenSize.maxRight - m_MultiScreenSize.minX, m_MultiScreenSize.maxBottom - m_MultiScreenSize.minY, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);` is called, all the arguments are 0 (apart from the `PixelFormat`) and this is causing an Argument Exception to be thrown. Any idea what may cause that?

Comment: Regards my comment above: I brainlessly (and foolishly) ran this through a VB > C# converter and that's what caused my problem. Specifically, the members of the struct weren't getting set! This code works great! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) of the form to `Manual` before setting the Location of the SnippingTool, otherwise it gets placed on the primary screen no matter what. Do this either in the constructor or in your using statement and it should fix your issue.

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only a part of the solution, and I already had this set in .Designer file.  I'll answer the question and describe the way to make it work below.

Comment: @Sphynx: I see. I didn't see that statement so that's why I thought  it was the cause. I got it working on my computer and used `WorkingArea` (as you describe in your answer) but didn't know that they both were required to make it work. I'm glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you doing anything wrong.  I can't test this, don't have the setup right now.  Bounds is a bit tricky, there's a bunch of code behind it that ensures that the form can't be displayed off-screen.  As an alternative, you could set the Location property instead and override OnLoad() in SnippingTool to set the WindowState property.

Comment: Tried many different ways. The post above has been edited to reflect the latest version. Now it displays form on the correct screen, but fails to draw anything on it. The form appears blank, like if we remove CopyFromScreen. Any thoughts?

Comment: I dunno, still don't have the hardware.  If you mail it to me then I'll fix it.  There's a bug in Graphics.CopyFromScreen(), it cannot see layered windows.  Put notepad.exe on that screen to check.

Comment: Sure I can send it.  Do you need only SnippingTool class or entire test app? I think it's not related to layered windows...

Comment: I also don't have a second monitor or anyone else to help me out with this problem. The only thing I can offer is a bounty, in which you probably won't be interested. But I upvoted your comment anyway, since it was fun :)

Comment: No, you're right, but I'm giving the app to someone else with extra monitor for testing. He is not a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I have create the helper class to capture the selected area on specific screen where control reside. It works on multiple screens.

[image: Displays]

The idea is taken from multiple online resources that basically Freeze the Screen and put into PictureBox .NET control.

Here's the codes:

```
public class CaptureScreen : IDisposable
{
    readonly Control control;
    readonly Pen penSelectedAreaScreenShot;

    Form frmPictureBox = null;
    PictureBox pictureBoxScreenShot = null;
    Point selectedScreenShotStartPoint;
    Size selectedScreenShotSize;
    bool isMouseDownSelectedScreenShot = false;

    public event Action<object, Bitmap> SelectedScreenAreaCaptured;

    public event Action<object, Exception> ScreenCaptureFailed;

    public CaptureScreen(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("control");
        }

        this.control = control;

        this.penSelectedAreaScreenShot = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        this.penSelectedAreaScreenShot.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
    }

    public void BeginStart()
    {
        #region Setup the Picture Box for ScreenShot

        if (this.frmPictureBox != null)
        {
            this.frmPictureBox.Close();
            this.frmPictureBox.Dispose();
            this.frmPictureBox = null;
        }

        if (this.pictureBoxScreenShot != null)
        {
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Dispose();
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot = null;
        }

        this.frmPictureBox = new Form
        {
            BackColor = Color.Black,
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent,
            TopLevel = true,
            TopMost = true,
            Top = 0,
            Left = 0,
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized,
            KeyPreview = true
        };

        this.pictureBoxScreenShot = new PictureBox
        {
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        };
        this.frmPictureBox.Controls.Add(this.pictureBoxScreenShot);

        #endregion

        #region Capture the Screen

        Bitmap screenShotBitmap = null;
        Graphics graphics = null;
        MemoryStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            Screen currentScreen = Screen.FromControl(this.control);

            screenShotBitmap = new Bitmap(currentScreen.Bounds.Width, currentScreen.Bounds.Height);

            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShotBitmap as Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(currentScreen.Bounds.X, currentScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, screenShotBitmap.Size);

            stream = new MemoryStream();
            screenShotBitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Size = screenShotBitmap.Size;
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (this.ScreenCaptureFailed != null)
            {
                this.ScreenCaptureFailed(this, ex);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
                stream = null;
            }

            if (graphics != null)
            {
                graphics.Dispose();
                graphics = null;
            }

            if (screenShotBitmap != null)
            {
                screenShotBitmap.Dispose();
                screenShotBitmap = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        this.frmPictureBox.KeyDown += this.frmPictureBox_KeyDown;

        this.pictureBoxScreenShot.MouseMove += this.pictureBoxScreenShot_MouseMove;
        this.pictureBoxScreenShot.MouseDown += this.pictureBoxScreenShot_MouseDown;
        this.pictureBoxScreenShot.MouseUp += this.pictureBoxScreenShot_MouseUp;

        this.frmPictureBox.Show(this.control);
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        if (this.frmPictureBox != null)
        {
            this.frmPictureBox.Close();
            this.frmPictureBox.Dispose();
            this.frmPictureBox = null;
        }

        if (this.pictureBoxScreenShot != null)
        {
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Dispose();
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot = null;
        }

        this.isMouseDownSelectedScreenShot = false;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    void frmPictureBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Exit();
        }
    }

    void pictureBoxScreenShot_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Image == null)
        {
            this.Exit();
            return;
        }

        if (this.isMouseDownSelectedScreenShot)
        {
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Refresh();

            this.selectedScreenShotSize = new Size(
                e.X - this.selectedScreenShotStartPoint.X,
                e.Y - this.selectedScreenShotStartPoint.Y);

            // Draw the selected area rectangle.
            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(this.penSelectedAreaScreenShot,
                this.selectedScreenShotStartPoint.X, this.selectedScreenShotStartPoint.Y,
                this.selectedScreenShotSize.Width, this.selectedScreenShotSize.Height);
        }
    }

    void pictureBoxScreenShot_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.isMouseDownSelectedScreenShot)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.selectedScreenShotStartPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }

            this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Refresh();

            this.isMouseDownSelectedScreenShot = true;
        }
    }

    void pictureBoxScreenShot_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Image == null)
        {
            this.Exit();
            return;
        }

        isMouseDownSelectedScreenShot = false;

        this.frmPictureBox.Hide();

        // Check whether there is something get selected.
        if (this.selectedScreenShotSize.Width > 0 && this.selectedScreenShotSize.Height > 0)
        {
            Bitmap selectedAreaBitmap = null;
            Graphics graphics = null;
            Bitmap screenShotBitmap = null;

            try
            {
                selectedAreaBitmap = new Bitmap(this.selectedScreenShotSize.Width, this.selectedScreenShotSize.Height);

                graphics = Graphics.FromImage(selectedAreaBitmap);

                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                screenShotBitmap = new Bitmap(this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Image, this.pictureBoxScreenShot.Size);
                graphics.DrawImage(screenShotBitmap, 0, 0, new Rectangle(this.selectedScreenShotStartPoint, this.selectedScreenShotSize), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                if (this.SelectedScreenAreaCaptured != null)
                {
                    this.SelectedScreenAreaCaptured(this, selectedAreaBitmap);
                }
                else
                {
                    Clipboard.SetImage(selectedAreaBitmap);
                    MessageBox.Show(this.control, "Selected Screen is copied to Clipboard.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (this.ScreenCaptureFailed != null)
                {
                    this.ScreenCaptureFailed(this, ex);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (screenShotBitmap != null)
                {
                    screenShotBitmap.Dispose();
                    screenShotBitmap = null;
                }

                if (graphics != null)
                {
                    graphics.Dispose();
                    graphics = null;
                }

                if (selectedAreaBitmap != null)
                {
                    selectedAreaBitmap.Dispose();
                    selectedAreaBitmap = null;
                }
            }
        }

        this.Exit();
    }

    #region IDisposable Member

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Exit();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
   CaptureScreen captureScreen = new CaptureScreen(this);

   // If event not implement, then by default it will copied to clipboard.
   //captureScreen.SelectedScreenAreaCaptured += delegate(object am_sender, Bitmap am_selectedAreaBitmap)
   //{
        //string destFilename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), String.Format("Capture_{0}.png", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));
        //am_selectedAreaBitmap.Save(destFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);                
   //};

   // Implements this to handle the exception that occurs during screen capture.
   //captureScreen.ScreenCaptureFailed += delegate(object am_sender, Exception am_ex)
   //{
        //MessageBox.Show(this, am_ex.Message, "Unable to Capture the Screen", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
   //};

   captureScreen.BeginStart();
```