# How to Grab Predefined Region coordinate value for screenshot?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Equivalent of Snipping Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123776/net-equivalent-of-snipping-tool)

My code below is taking screenshot for the whole screen, but I would like to take a screenshot with a pre-defined region. I prefer to click on a button then drag and select the region I want to grab x, y, destinationX, destinationY value. Can someone give me a hint or sample how to do that?

```
bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, 
                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

// Create a graphics object from the bitmap
gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

// Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner                    
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                             Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                             0,
                             0,
                             Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                             CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really done much bitmap/graphics work but can you simply not capture the X,Y co-ordinates of the mouse_down and mouse_up events and then use those in your CopyFromScreen method

Something like:

```
 private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        startX = e.X;
        startY = e.Y;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        endX = e.X;
        endY = e.Y;
    }
```

You can then do a little math to determine the size of the area to transfer and feed that into your method.