# Capturing region of a screen

Tags: c#, screenshot, capture, crop, region

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Equivalent of Snipping Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123776/net-equivalent-of-snipping-tool)

I'm making a screenshotting application. Currently, that application can take a screenshot of the full page but I want to be able to capture the region of a screen (You can select a region on the screen, like Gyazo does it).

Couldn't find any code that I could use.

Comment: You could capture the full screen and then present the user with a windows that displays the full picture and then provide cropping functionality inside _your_ window.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you need, this is a turorial from Abhishek sur about how to make screen captures wheather in Windows Forms or WPF applications with the possibility of prcising the region of the screen
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/04/screen-capture-using-wpf-winforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another site that explains how to capture the X,Y coordinates as well as some other useful functions you may want to implement in your existing application http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/Screen-capture-utility-in-C-NET.aspx