# How correct Bug drawing rectangle in desktop

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I would like to capture a desktop area drawing a rectangle in desktop.

For achieve this, I have developed a class called MouseHooker which install a global mouse hook , process mouse messages and exposes it out via callback with a delegate.

The hook code its ok, the outside "callback" I think too but has a strange bug.

It hook the mouse, but the rectangle its drawn only if after left mouse up, the mouse is moved.

I don't know why. Can you help me ? 
Thanks

MouseHooker internal callback

```
private static IntPtr MyCallbackFunction(int code, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // messsage not processed
        if ( code < 0 )
            SafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero,code,wParam,lParam);

        // check outside callback subscribed to delegate (NOT IMPORTANT )
        if ( state != HookState.CallBackError )
        {

            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hk = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            MouseHookArgs m; // this struct only contains mouse coordinates and button
            m.x = hk.pt.x;   // clicked information
            m.y = hk.pt.y;

            // process mouse messages
            switch ((MouseMessages)wParam)
            {

              case MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                  m.button = MouseButtons.M_MOVE;
                  mc(m); // call outside "callback" mc its a delegate
                break;          

                case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP:
                  m.button = MouseButtons.LB_UP;
                  mc(m);
                break;

                case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN:                     
                     m.button = MouseButtons.LB_DOWN;
                     mc(m);
                break;

                // more mouse message processing
         }
               // CallNextHookEx
         return SafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero,code,wParam,lParam);
}
```

"Callback" in the form ( here the bug, why ?)

```
void callbackrect( MouseHookArgs args )
    {

        switch (args.button)
        {
            case ppk.Hooks.MouseButtons.LB_UP:

                clean = true;
                ok = true;

                dest.X = args.x; // this struct its a Point
                dest.Y = args.y;

                // put destination mouse coordinate in form label
                capt.Text = string.Format("X: {0} , Y: {1}", dest.X, dest.Y);

            break;

            case ppk.Hooks.MouseButtons.LB_DOWN:                

            if ( clean )
            {                    
                clean = false;
                ok = false;
            }
                origin.X = args.x; // get origin mouse coordinate (to draw rectangle )
                origin.Y = args.y;

                // put origin mouse coordinate in form label 
                rat.Text = string.Format("X: {0} , Y: {1}", origin.X, origin.Y);

            break;    

        }

        // Invalidate & Update Desktop RECT Unmanaged because it's a efficient
        SafeNativeMethods.InvalidateRect(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);
        SafeNativeMethods.UpdateWindow(IntPtr.Zero); 

        if (ok && clean)  // Graphics g it's static and created in another location.
                          // Managed because creating a Pen, get DC, etc it's a pain
                          // and need more unmanaged code. So, why not use graphics ?                                  
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, origin.X, origin.Y, dest.X - origin.X, dest.Y - origin.Y);                                                     
    }
```

Comment: "MouseHooker"... nice ;)

Comment: Where is callbackrect used and how ?

Comment: @Tigran The main form contains a MouseHooker delegate with this prototype public delegate void MouseCallBack(MouseHookArgs mas); This delegate it's binded to callbackrect function, so when the hook it's installed, the "original" mouse messages are processed by MyCallBackFunction and callbackrect it's called via mc delegate.

Comment: delegate = typesafe "pointer" to funcion

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Equivalent of Snipping Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123776/net-equivalent-of-snipping-tool)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you say that when the rectangle is drawn, the position it's drawn in is offset from where you clicked.

If it's only a small amount, then it may be a rounding error. MSLHOOKSTRUCT defines pt as a point, which is a struct of two floats, not two ints.
([More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Any other error is to do with the difference of where your pointer is mesured from (the edge of the screen) and where your drawing event is mesured from (which we can't see, because you didn't post where the graphics object is set up)

Hope this helps!