# Enable user to select control/window from another process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

How can I enable user to select a control from any window? Something like inspect.exe or WinySpy++ can do (see screenshot).

[image]

EDIT:
By "select a control" I mean how can I get handle of the control under the mouse pointer so that I can then do something with it (e.g. draw box around it, get it's position and name). I know I need to use WinAPI, just don't know where to start (how to get handle of the control under the mouse pointer).

Comment: What do you mean by *"select a control"*? Set focus to it? Invoke it's associated command? Something else altogether?

Comment: It inspect OS messages. You have to check the Windows API for this.

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for not explaining it better from the start.

Comment: `GetCursorPos`, `WindowFromPoint`.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, that's it. Do you have any thought on drawing rectangle around "selected" control? Also, if you want please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Create a borderless maximized form, set its BackgroundImage property to a screenshot you made with Graphics.CopyFromScreen().  Draw the rectangle with the Paint event.  Basic code you need is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but I like more approach used in WinSpy++. If it fails I'll try the screenshot one ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's something to start from:  (this is very **rough** and needs more work!)

1. To a blank Form, add a PictureBox and four Labels.
2. Change the BorderStyle of the PictureBox to FixedSingle.
3. Add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` up at the top of the
   code with the other `using` statements.
4. Wire up the MouseDown(), MouseMove, and MouseUp() events of the
   PictureBox to the respective methods below.
5. Run it and drag the PictureBox around the screen...

[image: Very Rough Spy++ Example]

The code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    public const int WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;
    public const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point point);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr handle, StringBuilder ClassName, int MaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr handle, int msg, int Param1, int Param2);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr handle, int msg, int Param, System.Text.StringBuilder text);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle, out RECT Rect);

    public class WindowInfo
    {
        public IntPtr Handle;
        public string ClassName;
        public string Text;
        public Rectangle Rect;

        public WindowInfo(IntPtr Handle)
        {
            this.Handle = Handle;
            this.ClassName = GetWindowClassName(Handle);
            this.Text = GetWindowText(Handle);
            this.Rect = GetWindowRectangle(Handle);
        }
    }

    WindowInfo LastWindow = null;
    WindowInfo CurWindow;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point pt = Cursor.Position;
            this.Text = "Mouse Position: " + pt.ToString();
            this.CurWindow = new WindowInfo(WindowFromPoint(pt));

            label1.Text = "Handle: " + this.CurWindow.Handle.ToString("X");
            label2.Text = "Class: " + this.CurWindow.ClassName;
            label3.Text = "Text: " + this.CurWindow.Text;
            label4.Text = "Rectangle: " + this.CurWindow.Rect.ToString();

            if (this.LastWindow == null)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(this.CurWindow.Rect, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick);
            }
            else if (!this.CurWindow.Handle.Equals(this.LastWindow.Handle))
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(this.LastWindow.Rect, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick);
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(this.CurWindow.Rect, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick);                   
            }

            this.LastWindow = this.CurWindow;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            if (this.LastWindow != null)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(this.LastWindow.Rect, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick);

                // ... do something with "this.LastWindow" ...

            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetWindowClassName(IntPtr handle)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
        GetClassName(handle, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
        return buffer.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr handle)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH,0,0) + 1);
        SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, buffer.Capacity, buffer);
        return buffer.ToString();
    }

    public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        RECT rect = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);
        return new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, (rect.Right - rect.Left) + 1, (rect.Bottom - rect.Top) + 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `GetCursorPos` function to get the current cursor position.

Use `WindowFromPoint` to to get the window that contains the specified point.

As for drawing a rectangle, look at the [source code of WinSpy++](https://github.com/strobejb/winspy/blob/master/src/FindTool.c#L88).

Comment: Other useful API calls: GetWindowText, GetClassName, GetWindowLongA, GetWindowRect ... check pinvoke.net for the declarations.