# How to Search Windows Media Player Window?

Tags: c#, handle, windows-media-player, intptr

I need to return the IntPtr of the windows windows media player, but only that when it goes through the IntPtr line it returns `0x00000000` ie `IntPtr.Zero`. This should not be happening because it is the Windows Media Player itself.

I've already left the Windows Media Player window open while debugging this code, but it still returns IntPtr.Zero. What do I need to do to change this?

At the time of giving the command below, returns `0x00000000`

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("wmplayer", null);
```

Here is the code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

public IntPtr ScreenHandle() {
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("wmplayer", null); // here is the problem   
    return hWnd;         
}
```

Comment: My Windows Media Player Class Name comes up as "WMPlayerApp".

Comment: @Idle_Mind Wow, thank you very much. It works

Comment: @Idle_Mind How do I know my Windows Media Player?

Comment: You could use my [Starter Spy++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023047/2330053) example to see the class name of a window.

Comment: Helped me a lot