# Get the handle of a window with class name substring match

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm trying to obtain the handle to a window whose class name unfortunately changes (not my process). Only the first part of the class name stays constant (`Afx:ControlBar:`). It's also not a top process but rather a subwindow of another window.

I know that for a full string match on the class name, I could use

```
var controlBar = FindWindowEx(_parentWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "Afx:ControlBar:ac39000", "");
```

And I also know that I could just iterate through all  child windows of `_parentWindow` using the `childAfter` parameter of `FindWindowEx`, but I'm not sure how I'd get the className from the returned IntPtr object.

Is there an easy way to get the desired window handle from a known className substring?

Comment: "but I'm not sure how I'd get the className from the returned IntPtr object" Given an `IntPtr` to a window handle, you can use the [GetClassName() API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) to get the class name. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023047/2330053) for an example.

Comment: If you know the parent use `EnumChildWindows` to enumerate its children, otherwise `EnumWindows` to enumerate top-level windows and then enumerate the children. `GetClassName` to get the class of each window returned to the enumeration.

Comment: thanks for the useful suggestions, I've posted the solution I found based on your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the useful example referred to by @Idle_Mind in the comments, here's how I solved it using `GetClassName()`.

```
private static string GetWindowClassName(IntPtr handle)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
    GetClassName(handle, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
    return buffer.ToString();
}

private IntPtr GetControlBar(IntPtr startPointer)
{
    while (true)
    {
        startPointer = FindWindowEx(_parentWindow, startPointer, null, "");
        var className = GetWindowClassName(startPointer);
        if (className.StartsWith("Afx:ControlBar")) return startPointer;
        // if we have iterated all windows,, break
        if (startPointer == IntPtr.Zero) break;
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```