# Move System.Drawing.Rectangle to a different area on Screen

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am creating a screen capture & crop utility using [answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/1431250)
The code draws a rectangle (System.Drawing.Rectangle) on the screen and saves a cropped image.

I need to make this rectangle movable to a different area on the screen without changing the  size. 
How can I achieve this?

**What did not work for me?**

I tried this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime), works very good to move controls on the screen.
For this code to work correctly I would need to draw rectangle on a container control.
Which container can be used to wrapping?

Being a succesful web developer I used to think that I can write for WinForms also... I was wrong :-( Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# Windows Forms to change the location of a rectangle you do the following

```
rect.Location = new Location(x,y);
```

Where x and y are the coordinates (relative to the window's origin) that you want to move it to.

Here's a link to [The MSDN Page on System.Drawing.Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)