# Win32API block mouse effects

Tags: winapi, events, hook, mouse, block

I'm currently programming in c++ with the native windows library. Here is the thing: my program has to allow the user to capture a part of his screen. He has to select an area of the screen (with the mouse) while pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Thus the question is how to disable the **mouse effects** (text selection on websites for example...) while he's pressing the the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make a screenshot, let the user crop that bitmap.  Sample implementation [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/17034) in not-your-favorite language.

Comment: You can set up a [LowLevelMouseProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx) hook. It allows you to filter mouse messages, and prevent them from being passed to the target window procedure.