# How to paint on Picturebox VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have start a new project and i search for some solution to paint on a picturebox

with this code i am able to draw on a form but the i need to draw on a picture box, i have try multiple ways but i can not find the way to do it on the screenshoot in the picturebox
What i need to change to get it work?
This is my code

```
Public Class Form3

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand
End Sub

Dim mustPaint As Boolean = False

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    mustPaint = True
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If mustPaint Then
        Dim graphic As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
        graphic.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.X, e.Y, 10, 5)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    mustPaint = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("c:\\dcap.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = screenshot
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have rights to write directly to `c:\`? What error message do you get?
 Maybe try without saving the image file

```
'screenshot.Save("c:\\dcap.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

This absolutely puts a screenshot on the PictureBox. I don't know what else to tell you

```
PictureBox1.Image = screenshot
```

Here, I clicked the button 6 times and it kept working!

[image]

Comment: I have try like you show but then its paint only on a form wen i press the button to load the screenshot on the picture box the i am not able to paint on the screenshot only on the form

Answer (score -1):

Well after to try so many times i got it work
This is the working code

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Public Class Form3

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
End Sub

Dim mustPaint As Boolean = False
Private lastPT As Point
Private signature As New GraphicsPath

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            lastPT = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim curPt As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            signature.AddLine(lastPT, curPt)
            lastPT = curPt
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            signature.StartFigure()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, signature)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    signature.Reset()
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim bmp As New Drawing.Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
    PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PictureBox1.ClientRectangle)
    bmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "test.bmp"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Sub
Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    mustPaint = True
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If mustPaint Then
        Dim graphic As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
        graphic.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.X, e.Y, 10, 5)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    mustPaint = False
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("c:\\dcap.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    'PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = screenshot
    PictureBox1.Image = screenshot


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: So in the end, `PictureBox1.Image = screenshot`. If my answer wasn't enough (I suspect it wasn't since you dumped a lot more code here) then could you explain how you fixed it?

Comment: Yes Of Course , what i deed is to test all the possiblity s and what i needed to do is other story in this line in needed PictureBox1_Paint

Comment: i not heaved defined like this before so way i not able to paint on the top of it

Comment: and like that <code>If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, signature)
    End If</code>

Comment: I use a pen to paint on the screenshot or my loaded photo

Comment: and i can save all the alterations done on it after paint

Comment: `signature` is not even in your original question.

Comment: No Its true because i have give up from the first option to this one

Comment: The fisrt options i get paint but only on a form and the solution i have find it is with the signature so way i have change

Comment: `PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = screenshot` does not put the image on the PictureBox. `PictureBox1.Image = screenshot` does. That's how we fixed your problem.

Comment: No Not That part That One Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, signature)
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I Solved By Paint Direct On The PictureBox Item And Then save all the alterations in one file only ,clear button etc after to know how to do its easy to remake correct.

Comment: In My first quest is how to paint on a picturebox photo so on the first code i can only paint on a form but after add picturebox on the top of it i continue to paint there but i can not see because i have the picture box there and there is no configuration or code to make it transparent so i needed to find a way to do it, Well there is the problem here: i needed to find way to solve this enigmatic code

Comment: This is put the image on it PictureBox1.Image = screenshot

Comment: And Then Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("c:\\dcap.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    'PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = screenshot
    PictureBox1.Image = screenshot

Comment: And save button Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim bmp As New Drawing.Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
    PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PictureBox1.ClientRectangle)
    bmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "test.bmp"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Sub

Comment: In My Opinion This Is The Part Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, signature)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    signature.Reset()
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub

Comment: You can Find More About Here  » VB.NET » VISUAL BASIC LANGUAGE
VB.NET Method Signatures

Comment: Here is the title of your question: `How to paint on Picturebox VB.net`. And your question itself: `I have start a new project and i search for some solution to paint on a picturebox. with this code i am able to draw on a form but the i need to draw on a picture box, i have try multiple ways but i can not find the way to do it on the screenshoot in the picturebox What i need to change to get it work? This is my code` *My answer solved this*. So if you had another question, you needed to make a new question on StackOverflow. It is also very hard to understand what you are saying. Good luck