# Window finder tool (Like Spy++/Autoit)

Tags: c#, windows, spy++

I have noticed that many apps use (what seems like) the exact same control to find/select external windows. The tool looks like this:

[image: Windows finder tool]

Is this a standard component that I can import from somewhere? Maybe it just has a weird name I can't find?

I've nearly replicated the functionality but this finder tool looks much better than mine. Here's some screenshots of just two of the places I've seen this component:

[image: Finder tool in the wild]

Comment: I think such a question is off-topic here. You can ask for libraries at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Be sure to define your needs regarding OS, license and cost.

Comment: It is not a standard tool.   [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/17034) gets you half-way there, you'll have to add WindowFromPoint() and GetWindowRect() to know how to draw the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I started searching for Spy++ source code and came across many examples!

- [joeyespo/window-finder-control](https://github.com/joeyespo/window-finder-control)
- [r1pper/WindowSpy](https://gist.github.com/r1pper/5560944)
- [Custom VCL Control for getting window handles. (Spy++ style reticle)](https://chapmanworld.com/2018/10/04/custom-vcl-control-for-getting-window-handles-spy-style-reticle/)
- [MS Spy++ style Window Finder](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1698/MS-Spy-style-Window-Finder)
- [.NET Object Spy and InvokeRemote](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16481/NET-Object-Spy-and-InvokeRemote)
- [WinSpy.ahk - Window Information Tool](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28220)

Thanks for the help everyone!