# Creating macro to take and save screenshot and paste saved location into clipboard

Tags: docker, batch-file, window

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://sofiabelen.github.io/blog/anki-vim.html) and countered a problem with step 4. This step essentially binds a keyboard shortcut to a bash script that uses [scrot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Screen_capture) and [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip) to save a screenshot and pastes the saved location to clipboard.

If I were using a Linux operating system I could follow this instruction, but currently I am using a [Docker Ubuntu Container](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) hosted on Windows 10. If I try to use xclip or scrot I get the following errors respectively.

xclip error:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

scrot error:

```
Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
```

To work around this I've thought about replicating step 4 on my host machine with a combination of snip & sketch, [clip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clip), and binding a window shortcut to a batch file. There are many issues with this, the main issue being the fact that snip & sketch doesn't automatically save your screenshots, so I'd have to manually save after each screenshot.

My goal is to save a screenshot to a specified location and paste the saved location into my clipboard.  Emphasis on image location because I am aware that snip & sketch copies the screenshot onto your clipboard; this is a problem I can't paste an image into vim.

To perform these series of commands on Docker or my host machine is fine.

Comment: Maybe you can check https://superuser.com/questions/75614/take-a-screen-shot-from-command-line-in-windows for another tool to take a screenshot from the command line and autosave it to a file

Comment: @leaf, really helpful comment. I resolved the crux of my issue with this [batch file](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/screenCapture.bat). The only issue now is how would I modify the batch file such that I can specify the area to take the screenshot, rather than taking a screenshot of my entire screen/application?

Comment: The batch file actually runs C# code to capture an image from the active window area. You could start from line 58 `private Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle) ...`

Comment: Copying/Editing code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123776/net-equivalent-of-snipping-tool), I think I have an idea on how to fully implement this. I'll post my implementation here when I finish in case another user has a similar question.